# How do I add a new action to a class that inherits from an MVC controller

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a .Net Core (3.1) MVC application, and I'm trying to add a new action to a controller.  However, given the architecture of this solution, I'm very limited to what I can change.

Essentially I have an MVC controller, and a class that inherits from this controller that overrides some of the existing actions.  That's working fine, but I need to add a new action to this inherited controller, and I cannot find how to set the route up for it.

My main controller is:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Called HomeController.Index"
        });
    }
}
```

My derived class is:

```cs
public class HomeControllerExtended : HomeController
{
    public override IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Called HomeControllerExtended.Index"
        });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DoThis()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            Success = true,
            Message = "Called DoThis"
        });
    }
}
```

Accessing /Home/Index returns the JSON with the 'Called HomeControllerExtended.Index' message, which is expected.  However, accessing /Home/DoThis results in 404.

I've tried a few ways of adding a new route in Startup.cs, but none make any difference.  For example:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "DoThis",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=DoThis}");
});
```

But this makes no difference.

Firstly, is it possible for new actions to be added like this?  And if so, how do I configure the routing to find the new action?

Note that I cannot change HomeController at all, and the new action needs to be able to access the protected methods on HomeController.

Comment: Attach the route attribute at `DoThis` action as `[Route(“Home/DoThis”)]`.

Comment: @user1672994 Of course!  Thank you, yes, that did the trick.  I knew it'd be something really straight-forward.

Comment: posted that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the route attribute over `DoThis` action as shown below

```
[Route("Home/DoThis")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DoThis()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        Success = true,
        Message = "Called DoThis"
    });
}
```

With above now you can access the `DoThis` action using `/Home/DoThis` path.